# Vue.js add event listener inside instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Just started learning Vue yesterday and I love it. I'm trying to trigger an event when a user clicks on an anchor with a phone number:

```
var phoneNumbers = new Vue({
    el: "a[href^='tel:']",
    methods: {
        onClick() { console.log('a phone number was clicked'); }

    }
})
```

The issue is, I would like to (in this particular case), not have to add v-on:click="" to the actual element. This is because I'm dealing with a CMS where users may add links to phone numbers where they wouldn't be adding the vue attributes to the markup.

Any way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a reference to the component's root DOM element via [`this.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el).

You can add a click listener in the `mounted` hook (you'll also need to remove the listener in the `destroyed` hook as well):

```
mounted() {
  this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
},
destroyed() {
  this.$el.removeEventListener('click', this.onClick);
}
```

---

Here's a working example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

var phoneNumbers = new Vue({
  el: "a[href^='tel:']",
  methods: {
    onClick() { 
      console.log('a phone number was clicked'); 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.$el.removeEventListener('click', this.onClick);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<a href="tel:5555555555">555-555-5555</a>
```